# Captcha in Codeigniter can't verify text

Tags: php, codeigniter, captcha

I am trying to add a captcha for my login form in codeigniter.

The captcha is displaying fine. and problem is in verifying it.
When validate_captcha is being called the value from input post is correct but session value is new page value.(For example , if on the 1st page load captcha was 12345 (let's assume in second load it will be 54321) . then when in first load user inputs 12345 it will be checked with 54321.

What can I do?

Here is what I have tried

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends CI_Controller
{

    public function index()
    {

            $capCode = rand(10000, 99999);
            $this->session->set_userdata(array('captcha'=>$capCode));
            echo $this->session->userdata['captcha'];//for debug only

            $this->load->helper('captcha');
            $vals = array(
                'word' => $capCode ,
                'img_path' => CAPTCHA_PATH,
                'img_url' => base_url().CAPTCHA_PATH,
                'img_width' => '150',
                'img_height' => 30,
                'expiration' => 1200
                );

            $cap = create_captcha($vals);     

            $data = array('un' => $un,'defTab'=>'','captcha'=>$cap);

            $this->load->library('form_validation');



            //I need to load different data if form is result of a post($data['defTab'])
            if($this->input->post('submit'))
            {

                $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('captcha', 'Captcha', 'required|callback_validate_captcha');


                if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
                {
                    $data['defTab'] = 'what i need';
                    $this->load->view('login',$data);
                }
                else
                {
                    print_r($this->input->post());
                }      
            }
            else
            {
                $this->load->view('login',$data);
            }



    }

        public function validate_captcha()
        {
            $sss=$this->input->post('captcha');

            //I Use this line to find problem
            $this->form_validation->set_message('validate_captcha', 'session:'.$this->session->userdata['captcha'].'\nPosted val:'.$sss);

            if($sss!= $this->session->userdata['captcha'])
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the session during creation of your form:

```
    .
    .
    .
    } else {   
     if (isset($cap["word"])) {
           $this->session->set_userdata("word", $cap["word"]);
        }

     $this->load->view('login',$data);
    }
```

And during the validation check it with:

```
    if($this->input->post("word", TRUE) == $this->session->userdata("word")){
      // do something
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Before calling the create_captcha method use the below code to set the previous captcha

```
$this->session->set_userdata('prev_captcha',$this->session->userdata('captcha_word'));
```

provided captcha_word contains current captcha
and check like below

```
function checkCaptcha($str){

$word = $this->session->get('prev_captcha');
if(strcmp(strtoupper($str),strtoupper($word)) == 0){

  return true;
}else{

  return false;
}
```

}